# javascript or angular pass/databind by ref

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm new to javascript and even newer to angular and have a 'how do I do this' question: In my angular dashboard controller, I've written some code to make a tile look live like on a Windows phone. It just displays a number but counts up from 0 with live data binding. My question is how can refactor this out to another module so I can just call a method like zoomUpFromZero(databoundField). Coming from a C# background, I'd pass the databound field by reference. But in javascript, this doesn't seem to be possible.

```
var devCount = vm.deviceCount;
vm.deviceCount = 0;
var prom;

function zoomFromZero() {
  if (vm.deviceCount >= devCount) {
    stopit();
  } else {
    vm.deviceCount++;
    prom = common.$timeout(zoomFromZero, 30);
  }
};

function stopit() {
  common.$timeout.cancel(prom);
};

zoomFromZero();
```

I'd wrap the whole thing in a function and have it figure out the right number of millis between calls to make it take about a second. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/bUkGL/1/

The general idea here is to wrap the "zoom" into a [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), which are the things in Angular that are responsible for doing DOM manipulation. For posterity, here's the code:

```
angular.module('stackoverflow', []).directive('zoomToNumber', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            zoomToNumber: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('zoomToNumber', function(num) {
                var currentNumber = 0;

                function updateNumber() {
                    element.text(currentNumber);

                    if(currentNumber < num) {
                        $timeout(updateNumber, 20); // here's your interval
                    }

                    currentNumber++;
                }

                updateNumber();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Note that we're bringing in AngularJS's `$timeout` service, which is important, since it wraps `window.setTimeout` and wires it into Angular's digest processing. You can also, if you wanted to get really fancy, add things to the `scope` hash to allow parameterizing the interval, etc.

Comment: Nice! zoomy awesomeness.

Comment: Easiest solution and probably the right one -- decorate the element with the directive and it just works. Thanks! Now how to get my rep up so I can up vote...

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass a function into you zoom function that sets the field to simulate passing the field by reference. e.g.

```
function zoomRange(setField, minValue, maxValue) {
    setField(minValue);
    minValue++;

    if (minValue <= maxValue) {
        $timeout(function() {zoomRange(setField, minValue, maxValue);}, 50);
    }
};
```

You could call the function like this:

```
zoomRange(function(val) {vm.deviceCount = val}, 0, 10);
```

Then you could move the `zoomRange()` function to an external service.

Comment: I should have thought of that. Simple and elegant. Thanks rob!